# How to check image value in custom module in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, image, image-upload

Here, I would like to upload  image in admin panel grid form in magento. I create images upload in admin panel grid form. Here I attached my sample image upload coding.

```
[...]
$fieldset->addField('collar_image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'collar_image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('measurement_setter')->__('collar Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('measurement_setter')->__('collar Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));
[...]
```

When i save that image data into **MYSQL database** it results **`array`**.And i get response in that save script it results **`Array`**.

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $redirectPath   = '*/*';
        $redirectParams = array();

        // check if data sent
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);exit;
        if ($data) {
            $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);
            // init model and set data
            /* @var $model Magentostudy_News_Model_Item */
            $model = Mage::getModel('measurement_setter/setter');
 [...]
```

How to check image values whether correct or not? And How to get check image values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to upload the image in a specific folder and when you edit one of your entities that has an image, you should see the image near the input with an option to delete.
If so, here is what you need to do.
You need to create a custom renderer for the image field.

Create the file `app/code/local/[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/[Entity]/Helper/Image.php`

```
<?php
class [Vendor]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image
{
    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'/'.'your_folder'.
                $this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

now you have to make your form use this renderer.  In the add/edit form you should have a line like this:

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('....',array('legend' => ...)));
```

after this line add this:

```
$fieldset->addType(
        'image',
        Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('[vendor]_[module]/adminhtml_[entity]_helper_image')
    );
```

Now you should save the image when uploaded.
In your `saveAction` add this below `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();`

```
   $input = 'collar_image'; //the image input name
   $destinationFolder = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'your_folder';
   $imageName = '';
   try {
        if (isset($data[$input]['delete'])) {
            $imageName = '';
        } else {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($input);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
            $imageName =  $result['file'];
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() != Varien_File_Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
            throw $e;
        } else {
            if (isset($data[$input]['value'])) {
                $imageName = $data[$input]['value'];
            }
        }
    }
    $data[$input] = $imageName;
```

Then continue the normal saving process.

Replace in the code above the values between `[]` with your real values.

- [Vendor] => your module namespace
- [Module] => your module name
- [Entity] => your entity name

Comment: Hi @Marius..i create sample image upload in custom form but need to add more than one image upload in custom form it wont working ? when i add it will simply display image upload tag but doesnt working fine..kindly refer my another question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54856/how-to-create-more-than-one-custom-image-uploader-form-in-magento?

Comment: [Entity] means how to go folder. 

class Magebuzz_Banners_Adminhtml_Banners_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image