# How to create more than one custom image uploader form in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, image, image-upload, image-preview

Here, I customized [**Magentostudy_news**](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magentostudy_News-1.0.0.0.1.tgz) extension and create custom form in admin panel.When i create simple single image upload it working fine.but i need to add more then one image upload in custom form in admin panel,It wont working for me.

[image: TEXT CORRECTION]

Image file : **`Block/Adminhtml/Next/Edit/Tab/Image.php`**

```
 <?php
/**
 * News List admin edit form image tab
 *
 * @author Magento
 */
class Magentostudy_Next_Block_Adminhtml_Next_Edit_Tab_Image
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    /**
     * Prepare form elements
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /**
         * Checking if user have permissions to save information
         */
        if (Mage::helper('magentostudy_next/admin')->isActionAllowed('save')) {
            $isElementDisabled = false;
        } else {
            $isElementDisabled = true;
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('news_image_');

        $model = Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->getNewsItemInstance();


        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_fieldset', array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Image Thumbnail'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
        ));

        $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);

        $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Image'),
            'required'  => false,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('collarimage1', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'collarimage1',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('collar image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('collar image'),
            'required'  => false,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        )); 
        $fieldset->addField('chestimage', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'chestimage',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Chest image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Chest image'),
            'required'  => false,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_next_edit_tab_image_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Image Thumbnail');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Image Thumbnail');
    }

    /**
     * Returns status flag about this tab can be showen or not
     *
     * @return true
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns status flag about this tab hidden or not
     *
     * @return true
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve predefined additional element types
     *
     * @return array
     */
     protected function _getAdditionalElementTypes()
     {
         return array(
            'image' => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('magentostudy_next/adminhtml_next_edit_form_element_image')
        );
     }
}
```

When i added text-box,text-area,select,radio and check-box it will display in custom form.but when i add more than one image upload it display perfect but it will-not functioning properly.
[image: IMAGE ISSUES]

Image file : **`Block/Adminhtml/Next/Edit/Tab/Main.php`**

```
<?php
    /**
     * News List admin edit form main tab
     *
     * @author Magento
     */
    class Magentostudy_Next_Block_Adminhtml_Next_Edit_Tab_Main
        extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
        implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
    {
        /**
         * Prepare form elements for tab
         *
         * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
         */
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
            $model = Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->getNewsItemInstance();

            /**
             * Checking if user have permissions to save information
             */
            if (Mage::helper('magentostudy_next/admin')->isActionAllowed('save')) {
                $isElementDisabled = false;
            } else {
                $isElementDisabled = true;
            }

            $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

            $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('news_main_');

            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
                'legend' => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('News Item Info')
            ));

            if ($model->getId()) {
                $fieldset->addField('news_id', 'hidden', array(
                    'name' => 'news_id',
                ));
            }

            $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
                'name'     => 'title',
                'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('News Title'),
                'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('News Title'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ));

            $fieldset->addField('author', 'text', array(
                'name'     => 'author',
                'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Author'),
                'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Author'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ));
            /* $fieldset->addField('collarimage', 'text', array(
                'name'     => 'collarimage',
                'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('collarimage'),
                'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('collarimage'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ));*/


            $fieldset->addField('published_at', 'date', array(
                'name'     => 'published_at',
                'format'   => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'label'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Publishing Date'),
                'title'    => Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('Publishing Date'),
                'required' => true
            ));

            Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_next_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));

            $form->setValues($model->getData());
            $this->setForm($form);

            return parent::_prepareForm();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare label for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('News Info');
        }

        /**
         * Prepare title for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return Mage::helper('magentostudy_next')->__('News Info');
        }

        /**
         * Returns status flag about this tab can be shown or not
         *
         * @return true
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Returns status flag about this tab hidden or not
         *
         * @return true
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What are the procedure to add new image upload tag in custom form.Handle me in proper way..Kindly advise me..How to upload image in other image upload and retrieve preview section?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: HI @seanbreeden..I update my question.Kindly review it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found solution for  more than one image upload in that custom form.Its simple concept for adding image upload more than one in custom form.Here following procedure for that image upload concept:

**Step:1**

**Image file** : **`Block/Adminhtml/Next/Edit/Tab/Image.php`** add  custom image field tag in that image file.

```
[...]     
$fieldset->addField('collar_image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'collar_image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('measurement_setter')->__('collar Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('measurement_setter')->__('collar Image'),
            'required'  => true,
            'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
        ));

 [...]
```

**Step:2**

**Controller File**: **`controllers/Adminhtml/[ModuleName]Controller.php`** Add that below line into `saveAction()`function.

```
//Assign that values 
 if (isset($data['collar_image'])) {
                $collar_imageData = $data['collar_image'];
                unset($data['collar_image']);
            } else {
                $collar_imageData = array();
            }
  //collar Remove Image
                if (isset($collar_imageData['delete']) && $model->getCollar_image()) {
                    $imageHelper->removeImage($model->getCollar_image());
                    $model->setCollar_image(null);
                } 
//Upload new Collar Image upload tag
$imageFile = $imageHelper->uploadImage('collar_image');
                if ($imageFile) {
                    if ($model->getCollar_image()) {
                        $imageHelper->removeImage($model->getCollar_image());
                    }
                    $model->setCollar_image($imageFile);
                }
```

And then you can clear cache and index section in **`Var/Cache`** and **`Var/Index`**.

**NOTICE:**

**[Modulename]** =>your module name

Answer (score 1):

For file upload field the class attribute can't be set because Magento overrides the class and put the `input-file` on the file upload field.

`setAfterElementHtml` is helpful here and we can set `required-entry` class using custom JS as shown below.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image',
    'image',
    array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('vteams_productlabels')->__('Image'),
        'name'  => 'image',
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => 'this-class-never-works',
   )
)->setAfterElementHtml("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$('productlabel_image').addClassName('required-entry');</script>");
```